# How to close Snackbar on button click?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SnackBar` that tell me when I click on the button that is on it I need to close it. I tried to write the `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar()` method, but it gives an error, probably because I call it inside the showSnackBar method. Tell me, how can I close the `SnackBar` by clicking on the Refresh button?

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 0,
                  content: SystemMessagesSnackBar(
                    message: 'No internet access. Check your connection',
                    textButton: 'Refresh',
                    onPressed: ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(),
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.no_connection),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

**snackbar**

```
class SystemMessagesSnackBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SystemMessagesSnackBar(
      {Key? key,
      required this.message,
      required this.textButton,
      this.icon,
      this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  final String message;
  final String textButton;
  final SvgPicture? icon;
  final Function()? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 80,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                color: constants.Colors.purpleDark,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  icon != null
                      ? Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: icon!,
                        )
                      : const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Text(
                      message.toString(),
                      style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: onPressed,
                    child: Text(
                      textButton,
                      style: constants.Styles.tinyBookTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are doing `onPressed: myMethod(),` It's directly calling the method,

You can do

```dart
content: SystemMessagesSnackBar(
  message: 'No internet access. Check your connection',
  textButton: 'Refresh',
  onPressed: ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar,
),
```

or

```dart
onPressed: () =>
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a key to the scaffold and use `hideCurrentSnackBar`

```
scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
```

Or you can also use

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar()
```

Comment: I already tried to do this, but I get an error

Comment: Try setting a key and switch showing and closing of snackbar with that key

Comment: You mean this scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar(); ?

Comment: Yeah by setting a key to your scaffold

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Snackbar Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
 snackBar.setAction("Discard", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call your action method here
            snackBar.dismiss();
        }
    });

snackBar.show();
```

Comment: This question is related to flutter, please consider deleting android-java answer.